# Were the Supers born or created?

Tags: disney, powers, pixar, the-incredibles, incredibles-2

There is a theory surrounding the Supers in the *Incredibles* universe that the Supers were created by the government as part of a experimental program.

The main points of the theory are:

- No origin story for any of the Supers
- Nothing bad really happens after the Supers go into hiding
- The Government covers the costs of lawsuits filed against the Supers
- The Government institutes and pay for the Super Hero Relocation Program, as well as handling any cover ups and memory erasing.
- The Government must know the real identity of the Supers for the program to work.
- [None of the villains have powers.](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/189747/why-are-the-incredibles-villains-technologically-based)

There are some holes that could be poked in this theory, especially after the release of *Incredibles 2*; but is there any concrete evidence of how the Supers got their powers?

Comment: Current convention (dunno who started it or where it comes from) suggests we use the pixar tag and not disney, reserving disney for properties such as Frozen etc with are called "Disney's Frozen" (where as this is typically called "Pixars The Incredible's). Again, no disney tag. This is a pixar animation.

Comment: [The wikia](http://the-incredibles.wikia.com/wiki/Supers) claims the following but is unsourced (and admits as much): Supers are a humans who were born with, or given superpowers. Though, in all of the different forms of The Incredibles media, there are little to no answers on how supers get their powers, there is much room for speculation.

Comment: @Edlothiad I really no convention is the couple dozen questions on these films. If that is the case I would suggest editing the tag wikis or raising a meta. I would argue the experts in the Disney tag would likely be experts and interested in The Incredibles.

Comment: Look into the Pixar Theory. This provides fairly in-depth details regarding the Super's origin. http://www.pixartheory.com/,

Comment: Well with the exception of the Underminer, the villains from the movies had beef with supers, and if they had had powers then they might have made very different choices-- basically, they were villains *because they didn't have powers,* not the other way around.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Unclear

...but evidence points to the Supers being born with their powers.

I'll start off by saying it is quite evident from the first film that the "second set" of Supers were born with their powers, meaning Violet, Dashiell and Jack-Jack. E also seems to hold to the same assertion that two Supers having children should produce a Super.

> Edna: Shh! Darling! Shh! I cut it a little roomy for the free 
>   movement. The fabric is comfortable for sensitive skin, and can also withstand 
>   a temperature of over 1000 degrees. Completely bulletproof. And machine 
>   washable, darling. That's a new feature.
>
> Helen: What on earth do you think the baby will be doing?!
>
> Edna: Well, I'm sure I don't know, darling. Luck favors the 
>   prepared. **I didn't know the baby's powers, so I covered the basics.**
>
> Helen: Jack-Jack doesn't have any powers.
>
> Edna: **No?** Well, he'll look fabulous anyway.
>
> <sup>The Incredibles</sup>

With this being the case it would mean that the powers are genetic which would imply that they are born with their powers. This assertion seems to hold through for the following description is made of Syndrome on the official Pixar website implying that the others were born with them.

> **Syndrome wasn’t born with superpowers**, but envied the attention and admiration the Supers received. Of all the Supers, Mr. Incredible embodied everything Syndrome desired: strength, fame, and popularity. Highly intelligent and cunning, Syndrome now spends his days on a remote island on the other side of the world inventing gadgets and robots to carry out a diabolical plot.
>
> <sup>[Pixar, The Incredibles, Syndrome](https://www.pixar.com/feature-films/the-incredibles#the-incredibles-main)</sup>